# C# Vector3D Operator '-' cannot be applied t type 'Vector3D' and double

Tags: c#, math, vector, formulas, orbital-mechanics

The kind folks over at Space Exploration Beta have been helping me with calculating orbital elements but i have been stuck on applying one formula in C# for a bit of time and require a bit of advise.

The Formula is for the Eccentricity Vector using:

$$\vec e = \frac{\vec v \times \vec h}{\mu} \ - \frac{\vec r}{||r||}  $$

(e = v * h /mu - r / ||r||)

My code for the Formula is the following;

```
double V = 7770;
double R = 6771000;
double Mu = 4e+14;

Vector3D velocity = new Vector3D(0, V, 0);
Vector3D Radias = new Vector3D(R, 0, 0);

Vector3D H = Vector3D.CrossProduct(Radias, velocity);//Angular Momentum = r * v
 //e = v * h /mu - r / ||r||
Vector3D rh = Vector3D.CrossProduct(velocity, H);
double t = Radias.Length;
Vector3D e = Vector3D.Divide(rh, Mu) - R / t;
```

Now this brings up

> Operator '-' cannot be applied to operands of type 'Vector3D' and 'double'

Now i now it saying in can't divide a vector by a double but i am unsure on how to get around that, i thought of casting but i wouldn't know what to?

This is really at the edge of my Maths skills and C# maths programming.

Any Help would be greatly appreciated.

*EDIT* Here is one of my source [Materials](https://downloads.rene-schwarz.com/download/M002-Cartesian_State_Vectors_to_Keplerian_Orbit_Elements.pdf) that i am using so you can see the formula correctly.

*EDIT 2* Here is the working code:

`Vector3D e = Vector3D.Divide(rh, Mu) - Radias / Radias.Length;
double e1 = e.Length;
Console.WriteLine(e1);`

Brings a Answer that matches not only a answer provided by a user over a Space Exploration beta but a different version of the formula i tried. So the code and formula are good. Thanks for your assistance.

Comment: No it's saying you can't subtract a double from a vector, are you trying to subtract that value from all 3 unit elements of the vector?

Comment: you are trying to do vector minus number. This doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`r / ||r||` is the *unit vector* of your coordinate, i.e. `Radias / Radias.Length` = `(1, 0, 0)`:

```
Vector3D e = rh / Mu - Radias / Radias.Length
```

You simply mixed up the number `R` in your declaration of `Radias`, and `Radias` itself.

[Note that we can simply use the [overloaded division operation `/`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.media3d.vector3d.op_division(v=vs.110).aspx) instead of `Vector3D.Divide`]

Comment: *Face Palm* I'll give it a go tonight when i get home and see how it goes.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't say that you can't divide. It says that you can't subtract.
If you want to subtract a double to each component of a vector, you need to create a vector with it. In your case the problem is the last line you showed here:

```
Vector3D e = Vector3D.Divide(rh, Mu) - R / t;
```

In this line, `Vector3D.Divide(rh, Mu)` is a vector and  `R / t` is a double. For this to work, create a vector with the three component set to `R / t`:

```
Vector3D rt = new Vector3D(R / t, R / t, R / t);
Vector3D e = Vector3D.Divide(rh, Mu) - rt;
```

(Assuming you want to subtract R/t from all the component of your vector)

**EDIT:** looking again at your formula, are you sure that `R` shoudn't be a vector? it seems it is a vector in the base formula and isn't in your code

Comment: I added the Material that i am using and yes it appears that R should of been the Radias vector instead. It must of been a left over from when i was experimenting.

Comment: @Nzjeux, Did it work? By the way I see that this is your first question. If an answer solved it, you can **accept** it to mark the topic as resolved. see [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) if you want to know more about accepting answers

Comment: Ticked the one that worked, though this one probably would of done just as good.

Comment: Woops, sorry, didn't see you accepted one already. By the way, welcome to stakoverflow